# Как работать с шапкой (верхним колонтикулом), полоска где пишется название программы

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как работать с верхней шапкой (колонтикулом) приложения (где название), использую форму (шаблон) EmptyActivity.

Как добавить там что либо, как изменить?

Answer (score 3):

Эта часть интерфейса называется App Bar. В качестве App Bar можно использовать либо Action Bar, либо Toolbar.

Toolbar пришел на замену Action Bar, как более гибкое средство для создания App Bar.

Внедрить Toolbar в приложение можно следующим образом:

1. Унаследовать активити от `AppCompatActivity`:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Задать тему приложения, которая не содержит Action Bar:

   ```
   <application
       android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
   />
   ```
3. Разметить Toolbar в файле разметки:

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:elevation="4dp"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
   ```
4. Установить Toolbar в качестве App Bar:

   ```
   private Toolbar mToolbar;        
   ...

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
       mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
   }
   ```

Как работать с Toolbar – вопрос довольно объемный, поэтому приведу только основные моменты:

1. Установка заголовка:

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
   ```
2. Включение возможности обратной навигации:

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   ```
3. Установка значка:

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
   ```

Более подробную информацию можно найти в официальной документации по следующей ссылке: [Adding the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html).

Comment: то есть создать форму не "емптиактивити" а пустую и поставить туда toolbar? просто только начал осваивать программу. не могу даже информации найти

Comment: @Макс, Empty Activity – это и есть пустой шаблон.